# Difference between posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test and dunn.test

Tags: r, statistics, kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

I am currently searching a way to perform a dunn test in R. While doing that I came across multiple functions that have the Dunn test implemented.

```
library(dunn.test)
library(PMCMR)

dunn.test(x=mtcars[,"wt"], g= mtcars[,"cyl"])$P.adjusted

posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(x=mtcars[,"wt"], g=mtcars[,"cyl"], p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
```

The results however are completely different. Does anyone have experience with the dunn.test package? I want to use the Dunns test as a posthoc test after the Kruskal Wallis test.

Answer (score 1):

They use some different pre-sets. You can get identical results by applying a multiple testing correction and using alternative format p-values for the `dunn.test`:

```
dunn.test(x=mtcars[,"wt"], g= mtcars[,"cyl"], method = 'bonferroni', altp = TRUE)$P.adjusted
```

> ```
> Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
>
> data: x and group
> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 22.8067, df = 2, p-value = 0
>
>
>                            Comparison of x by group                            
>                                  (Bonferroni)                                  
> Col Mean-|
> Row Mean |          4          6
> ---------+----------------------
>        6 |  -1.836259
>          |     0.1990
>          |
>        8 |  -4.755941  -2.221605
>          |    0.0000*     0.0789
>
> alpha = 0.05
> Reject Ho if p <= alpha
> ```

```
posthoc.kruskal.dunn.test(x=mtcars[,"wt"], g=mtcars[,"cyl"], p.adjust.method="bonferroni")
```

> ```
> Pairwise comparisons using Dunn's-test for multiple   
>                          comparisons of independent samples 
>
> data:  mtcars[, "wt"] and mtcars[, "cyl"] 
>
>   4       6    
> 6 0.199   -    
> 8 5.9e-06 0.079
>
> P value adjustment method: bonferroni
> ```